# Function to combine multiple nested lists into one new list

Tags: python

Currently i have 3 lists:

```
swimv=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',1.25],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1], ['Run shoes+Goggles',1.33]]

cyclev=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',1.04],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1.2], ['Run shoes+Goggles',0.96]]

runv=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',0.67],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 0.8], ['Run shoes+Goggles',1.13]]
```

I want to combine them all into one list, so that output would be:

```
newlist=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',2.96],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 3], ['Run shoes+Goggles',3.42]]
```

Comment: I see you have already done it. Congratulations.

Comment: I meant using a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully Dynamic:

```
swimv=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',1.25],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1], ['Run shoes+Goggles',1.33]]

cyclev=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',1.04],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1.2], ['Run shoes+Goggles',0.96]]

runv=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',0.67],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 0.8], ['Run shoes+Goggles',1.13]]

newlist = []

for (a, b, c) in zip(swimv,cyclev,runv):
    newlist.append([a[0],a[1]+b[1]+c[1]])

print(newlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

answer:

```
swimv=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',1.25],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1], ['Run shoes+Goggles',1.33]]

cyclev=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',1.04],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1.2], ['Run shoes+Goggles',0.96]]

runv=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',0.67],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 0.8], ['Run shoes+Goggles',1.13]]

newlist = [[swimv[0][0],swimv[0][1]+cyclev[0][1]+runv[0][1]],[swimv[1][0],swimv[1][1]+cyclev[1][1]+runv[1][1]],[swimv[2][0],swimv[2][1]+cyclev[2][1]+runv[2][1]]]
print(newlist)
```

Comment: What if another list is added? Or another value to all lists? That requires many changes... Your code is not dynamic at all

Comment: Wait! I am checking

Comment: Check New Answer

Comment: Why did you post 2 answers? The second should be the only one...

Comment: Actually I was looking for better solution after your comment.